# Is Linear Regression problems always classified as supervised Machine learning problem

Tags: machine-learning, linear-regression

Is Linear Regression problems always classified as supervised Machine learning problem or in any specific condition it can be considered as unsupervised Machine learning

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It can be considered in some situations to be unsupervised machine learning.

Take the case of an autoregressive model for which the input is the value at time `t-1` and the value to predict is the value at time `t`. You have an unsupervised learning problem here, because the input is the same as the output like if you had an X with no Y such that the Y is the next value of X.

However, this way of thinking is stretched a lot and I'd be cautious about using the word "unsupervised learning" for a simple linear regression.

The fact is that some unsupervised learning problems can be learned through a supervised learning way of thinking. So a linear regression will always be a supervised learning algorithm, but it can be used to achieve unsupervised learning.

Comment: Mmmm... do you really think an AR model can be seen as unsupervised? There still is „supervision“... the only special thing is that x-1 (or longer lags of x) is the best way to describe x in some cases, especially random walks.

Comment: No, an autoregressive model is still supervised learning, not unsupervised.